# How to click on a button in React and open up a form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my app.tsx file with the included button that I want to click and open up the form. I am very new to react so any help would be appreciated thank you! I have also commented the button I want to use to open up the form in the code below.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const auth: Auth = {
    isAuthenticated,
    authenticate(cb: { (): void; (...args: any[]): void }) {
      setAuthenticated(true);
      setTimeout(cb, 100);
    },
    signout(cb: { (): void; (...args: any[]): void }) {
      setAuthenticated(false);
      setTimeout(cb, 100);
    },
  };
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <TopBar auth={auth} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage auth={auth} />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute auth={auth} path={dashboard}>

            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <PrivateRoute auth={auth} path="*">
          <Button onClick={navigateToForm} style={{ //this is the button i want to use to navigate
            height: 48, 
            width: 165,
            cursor: "pointer"  
          }}>REQUEST FORM</Button>  
            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

}

This is the code for my form that I used from material ui

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      '& .MuiTextField-root': {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        width: '25ch',
      },
    },
  }),
);

export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <TextField required id="standard-required" label="Required" defaultValue="Hello World" />
        <TextField disabled id="standard-disabled" label="Disabled" defaultValue="Hello World" />
        <TextField
          id="standard-password-input"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
        />
        <TextField
          id="standard-read-only-input"
          label="Read Only"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: true,
          }}
        />

        <TextField id="standard-search" label="Search field" type="search" />

      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a modal? https://material-ui.com/components/modal/

Comment: Is your form at a specific route path? And are you using React-Router?

Comment: Thanks for the modal suggestion, if i use modal, how can I link the modal to this button since it has a button within it as well?

Comment: It looks like you are using react-router. Have a look at https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html and then put your form inside a `<Route path='/my-from'><Form /></Route>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hi,
>   you can use

```
npm install react-modal --save
```

> from you terminal or command prompt to include the react modal package to your application.
>   then in your page you want to add the form on popup

```
    import Modal from 'react-modal';
    const customStyles = {
    content : {
        top                   : '50%',
        left                  : '50%',
        right                 : 'auto',
        bottom                : 'auto',
        marginRight           : '-50%',
        transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
      }
    };
```

> after this line 
>       const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
>
> on you  code add

```
const [modalIsOpen,setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

const navigateToForm = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
};

const closeModal =() => {
    setIsOpen(false);
};
```

> after your button place
>
> place the form inside the Modal Component

```
<Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={closeModal} style={customStyles} contentLabel="Example Modal"></Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please state clearly whether you want to show the form or navigate to the form page. in case you want to toggle the form component -**

**In you app.tsx file**

Import the form component

```
import Form from "path/to/component"
```

set the form view state (that toggles the form component)

```
const [form_view_state,update_form_view_state] = useState(0);
```

change onClick handler -

```
  <Button onClick={update_form_view_state(!form_view_state)} style={{
    height: 48,  
    width: 165,
    cursor: "pointer"  
  }}>REQUEST FORM</Button>
 {{(this.form_view_state)?<Form/>:""}}
```